# Generate customer ID's with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the program I am writing I need to generate a customer ID for every new client that gets registered into the system.

I want the list to start at 0001 and each new client ID is the next consecutive number from the last one registered (for example if the last registered client ID is 0234 the new registered ID needs to be 0235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you generate a number then append zeros to that number. This works:

```
n = 500
for i in range(1, n):
print "0" * (4 - len(str(i))) + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you have a basic background in python, I'm making it a crude way, I'm sure there are more sophisticated approaches, but this should do for now.
To start with:

1. Make a file that stores values *alone*, say **store**. (Initial value 0001)
2. In your main script, read `store`'s contents and feed them to a variable, say **n**.
3. An elegant way of generating client IDs in the format you specified would be `print "%04d" %(n+1)` - `%04d` specifies the 4 digit format you requested and `n` is the variable that stores your previous ID issued.
4. And last, overwrite the contents of `store` to the incremented value.
5. Remember to `close()` the file and you are all set!

For more information you can refer to the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) on string formatting.